# Minizinc: create an array of int pairs

Tags: arrays, minizinc

What is the Minizinc syntax to create an array of n int pairs like this:

{(x1,y1), (x2,y2),....(xn,yn)}

and how can I access to a specific element j to get, for example, its y value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MiniZinc you would currently use multi-dimensional arrays for this purpose. If, for example, you want to create `n` pairs of integer variables you can use:

```
array [1..n, 1..2] of var int: pairs;
```

You could then access each pair, but also each element. If, for example, you want to access pair `j`, then you can use the statement `pairs[j]`. This is an array of dimensions `1..2`; you can access the second element (`y`), using `pairs[j][y]`.

This approach allows you to use the variables directly, but you can also use pairs for predicates that call for arrays.